# what is the time complexity of Array#uniq method in ruby?

Tags: ruby

Can anyone please tell me which algorithm is internally used by ruby to remove duplicates from an ruby array using `Array#uniq` method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html):

```
static VALUE
rb_ary_uniq(VALUE ary)
{
    VALUE hash, uniq, v;
    long i;

    if (RARRAY_LEN(ary) <= 1)
        return rb_ary_dup(ary);
    if (rb_block_given_p()) {
        hash = ary_make_hash_by(ary);
        uniq = ary_new(rb_obj_class(ary), RHASH_SIZE(hash));
        st_foreach(RHASH_TBL(hash), push_value, uniq);
    }
    else {
        hash = ary_make_hash(ary);
        uniq = ary_new(rb_obj_class(ary), RHASH_SIZE(hash));
        for (i=0; i<RARRAY_LEN(ary); i++) {
            st_data_t vv = (st_data_t)(v = rb_ary_elt(ary, i));
            if (st_delete(RHASH_TBL(hash), &vv, 0)) {
                rb_ary_push(uniq, v);
            }
        }
    }
    ary_recycle_hash(hash);

    return uniq;
```

It has `O(N)` complexity

Answer (score 3):

Amortized O(n) as it [uses Hash internally](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/array.c#L3985).

Answer (score 3):

This depends on *which* "internals" you are talking about. There are 7 production-ready Ruby implementations in current use, and the Ruby Language Specification does not prescribe any particular algorithm. So, it really depends on the implementation.

E.g., this is [the implementation Rubinius uses](https://GitHub.Com/Rubinius/Rubinius/blob/master/kernel/common/array19.rb#L625-L641):

```
Rubinius.check_frozen

if block_given?
  im = Rubinius::IdentityMap.from(self, &block)
else
  im = Rubinius::IdentityMap.from(self)
end
return if im.size == size

array = im.to_array
@tuple = array.tuple
@start = array.start
@total = array.total

self
```

And this is [the one from JRuby](https://GitHub.Com/JRuby/JRuby/blob/master/src/org/jruby/RubyArray.java#L3136-L3157):

```
RubyHash hash = makeHash();
if (realLength == hash.size()) return makeShared();

RubyArray result = new RubyArray(context.runtime, getMetaClass(), hash.size()); 

int j = 0;
try {
    for (int i = 0; i < realLength; i++) {
        IRubyObject v = elt(i);
        if (hash.fastDelete(v)) result.values[j++] = v;
    }
} catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException aioob) {
    concurrentModification();
}
result.realLength = j;
return result;
```

Answer (score 1):

`It compares elements using their hash (provided by the Object#hash method) then compares hashes with Object#eql?.`

Source: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/array.c#L3976

Answer (score 1):

The time complexity is linear time i.e. O(n) as it uses Hash for the internal implementation of the 
algorithm.