# How to explain the disparity between performance of these ruby code?

Tags: ruby, optimization, time-complexity

I am performing some speed tests for the follow problem:

> Given 2 strings, s1 and s2, that contain only lowercase alphabets, output if the letters of s1 can be re-arranged such that s2 becomes a substring of s1.

I have obtained 2 solutions in ruby:

Version 1:

```
def scramble(s1,s2)
  if s1.length < s2.length
    return false
  end

  a = Array.new(26) { 0 }
  b = Array.new(26) { 0 }

  t1 = Time.now

  (0 ... s1.length).each do |x|
    a[s1[x].ord - 97] += 1
  end

  (0 ... s2.length).each do |x|
    b[s2[x].ord - 97] += 1
  end

  t2 = Time.now

  (0 ... 26).each do |x|
    if a[x] < b[x]
      return false
    end
  end

  puts t2 - t1

  return true
end
```

This version saves the count of characters in s1 and s2 in a direct addressing table and compares the count of each character. It should be clear that this code performs approximately 2 * (N + M) operations where N is the length of s1 and M is the length of s2.

Version 2:

```
def scramble(s1,s2)
  t1 = Time.now

  c = s2.chars
  c.uniq!
  t = c.all?{|x| s2.count(x)<=s1.count(x)}

  t2 = Time.now

  puts t2 - t1

  return t
end
```

This version also uses the count of characters in s1 and s2 but it does not use a direct addressing table. From what I understand, this version should perform approximately 26 * (N + M) operations because the complexity of the count() method is linear in the number of characters in a string and it is being called for each distinct character in the string.

When I perform

```
scramble('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'*500000, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'*500000)
```

The first version takes 4.424207s while the second takes only 2.574269s. I ran the test a few times with differing lengths of s1 and s2 and the results were consistent (version 2 is much faster than version 1). Due to their differing constants, I am really confused. Why does the code in version 2 run so much faster than version 1 despite having a much higher constant?

Could someone please advise me?

Comment: My only observation is that #2 benefits from calls to `uniq!` and `count` that are optimized in C whereas #1 mainly uses the Ruby interpreter. Incidentally, `uniq!` returns `nil` if no changes are made to the array, which could be an issue for short strings. Better to write `c = s2.chars.uniq`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland But uniq returns a new array right? That incurs extra overhead of array creation. By using uniq!, we can avoid this overhead because we return the same array that we operate on. Did I miss something?

Comment: `”abc”.chars.uniq! #=> nil` because `”abc”` was not changed. (See the doc for [Array#uniq!](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq-21)). You could write `c = s2.each_char.uniq` to avoid the temporary array. `s2.each_char` is an enumerator so this uses [Enumerable#uniq](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-uniq) rather than [Array#uniq](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq).

Comment: Hmm. According to the ruby docs that you linked, Enumerable#uniq also creates a new array.

Comment: Yes, but the enumerator `each_char` does not create an array (unlike `chars`, which does). Your use of `uniq!` is correct, however. I was thinking you were chaining it to another method, which is when a return value of `nil` is a problem. My apologies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's because standard library methods like `String#count` are implemented in C, which has way less overhead than executing the complicated Ruby expression `a[s1[x].ord - 97] += 1` 500000 times in a loop.

To see what I mean, try replacing these loops:

```
(0 ... s1.length).each do |x|
  a[s1[x].ord - 97] += 1
end

(0 ... s2.length).each do |x|
  b[s2[x].ord - 97] += 1
end
```

with calls to `String#count`:

```
(0 ... 26).each do |x|
  a[x] = s1.count((x + 97).chr)
  b[x] = s2.count((x + 97).chr)
end
```

With this change, it runs in 0.4 seconds on my machine (compared to 6.3s before)!

Comment: Now that is even more strange. Now the (modified) version 1 and version 2 have the exact same logic, but version 1 runs much faster than version 2 (0.643466s vs 2.727601s)! Why is that so?

Comment: Good question! It turns out if you move `t2 = Time.now` right after the call to `uniq!`, you can see that `uniq!` is taking most of the time (3.58s on my machine). If it weren't for the `uniq!`, it looks like both versions would indeed take almost exactly the same time.

Comment: More details on how `uniq` is implemented: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14200540/what-is-the-time-complexity-of-arrayuniq-method-in-ruby

Comment: In my earlier comment (now deleted) I was thinking hashes. I was suggesting that `('a'..'z').each { |c| h1[c]=s1.count(c); h2[c]=s2.count(c) }`, where `h1` and `h2` are hashes, made more sense than than using the arrays `a` and `b`.